# System backup on Linux - follow up

Tags: python, python-2.x, file-system, linux

This is a follow-up to [System backup on Linux](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106736/system-backup-on-linux). I've done a lot to my script since I asked my first question and I think I could improve a lot while doing this. The script still does the same, only a bit neater and cleaner. So let me explain what I changed, and sometimes why I've changed it.

- At first I changed all the names of my variables and constants (I hope that I understood constants correctly, that these are values that stay always the same, no matter on which system/host this script is executed). They're all now in "snake_case" and the constants are also in capital case.
- I started using the power of `os.path.join` instead of string concatenation. But there is one problem, `os.path.join` doesn't set a final `/` on the filepath, so I had to add the `DIR_PATH` constant on every path that was using the `backup_dir` key. Still looking around for a better solution for that..
- I also created a function for every major task to get a better structure in my script, also it makes it a lot easier for me to debug it. I want to make one function out of the two functions for getting the metadata and the old backups because they're practically doing the same except for the file ending, but I'm not sure if that's a good/better idea as using two. Also I'm not sure about the return values.
- The biggest change I've made in my backup function. I factored out the nesting to check the file age and add those files as a parameter to tar. The main reason for that was that I suddenly had around 120MB of parameters given to tar and somewhere below that lies the border of how many parameters tar can process. Now I'm using some nice tar features to make real incremental backups of my systems.

I'm really happy about what I did to my code, it looks pretty good and also works really well. But I guess there is still some space to improve it further, so I would appreciate any further feedback to my code!

```
import datetime
import os
import subprocess
import socket
import glob
import time

from stat import *

host = socket.gethostname()
date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

MOUNT_POINT = '/mnt/linuxbackup/'
NAS = '//172.19.3.5/backup/linuxserver/'
CREDENTIALS = 'sec=ntlm,credentials=/root/.backup.secret'
DIR_PATH = '/'

# configuration

backup_config = {
        'backup_dir' : os.path.join(MOUNT_POINT, host),
        'backup_name' : host + '.' + date,
        'backups_to_keep' : 4,
        'exclude_dirs' : ('/proc',
                         '/lost+found',
                         '/sys',
                         '/media',
                         '/var/cache',
                         '/var/log',
                         '/mnt',
                         '/dev',
                         '/run',
                         '/tmp'
                         ),
        }

exclude_dirs = ''
for a in backup_config['exclude_dirs']:
    exclude_dirs = exclude_dirs + '--exclude=%s ' %a
backup_config['exclude_dirs'] = exclude_dirs

def mount(mount_point, credentials, nas, backup_dir):
    """Checks if the NFS share for the backup
    exists (if not it creates it) and mounts it"""
    if os.path.exists(mount_point):
        if not os.path.ismount(mount_point):
            subprocess.check_call(['mount', '-t', 'cifs', '-o', credentials, nas, mount_point])
            if not os.path.exists(backup_dir):
                os.makedirs(backup_dir)
    else:
        os.makedirs(mount_point)
        subprocess.check_call(['mount', '-t', 'cifs', '-o', credentials, nas, mount_point])

def unmount(mount_point):
    """Unmounts the mounted backup directory"""
    if os.path.ismount(mount_point):
        subprocess.check_call(['umount', mount_point])


def get_previous_backups(backup_dir):
    """Returns a list of tar.bz2 compressed backup files matching the date format"""
    return [os.path.basename(x) for x in
            glob.glob(backup_dir + DIR_PATH + host + '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' +
                '-[0-9][0-9]' + '-[0-9][0-9]' + '.tar.bz2')]

def get_metafile(backup_dir):
    """Returns the metadata file for incremental tar backups"""
    return [os.path.basename(x) for x in
            glob.glob(backup_dir + DIR_PATH + host + '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' +
                '-[0-9][0-9]' + '-[0-9][0-9]' + '.metadata')]

def remove_old_backups(backup_dir, backups_to_keep, backup_name):
    """Gets a list of old backups and deletes the old ones"""
    fnames = get_previous_backups(backup_dir)
    metadata = get_metafile(backup_dir)
    print fnames
    while len(fnames) > backups_to_keep:
        print 'more than {} file(s) here!'.format(backups_to_keep)
        print 'Removing oldest file'
        file_times = {}
        access_times = []
        for file_name in fnames:
            print backup_dir + file_name
            mode = os.stat(backup_dir + DIR_PATH + file_name)[ST_MTIME]
            file_times[mode] = file_name
            access_times.append(mode)
            print mode

        access_times.sort()
        print file_times
        print access_times
        file_to_delete = file_times[access_times[0]]
        print 'Deleting file %s' %file_to_delete

        try:
            os.remove(backup_dir + DIR_PATH + file_to_delete)
            os.remove(backup_dir + DIR_PATH + file_to_delete[:-7] + 'log')

        except Exception as inst:
            print inst

        print '%s%s' %(backup_dir, backup_name)

def backup(backup_dir, backup_name):
    """is taking care of both, the incremental and the full backup,
    of a linux system"""
    fnames = get_previous_backups(backup_dir)
    metadata = get_metafile(backup_dir)
    print 'fnames = {}'.format(fnames)
    print 'metadata = {}'.format(metadata)
    print 'Backing up the system'
    print 'Working on %s' %backup_dir

    # Full Backup
    if datetime.date.today().strftime('%A') == 'Sunday':
        print 'doing complete backup of %s' %host
        command = ('nice -n 10 tar --create --verbose --preserve-permissions --bzip2 \
                --file={0}_FULL.tar.bz2 --listed-incremental={0}.metadata {1} > {2}.log 2>&1'
                .format(os.path.join(backup_dir, backup_name),
                    backup_config['exclude_dirs'],
                    DIR_PATH,
                    os.path.join(backup_dir, backup_name)))

    # Daily Backup
    else:
        print 'doing incremental backup of %s' %host
        command = ('nice -n 10 tar --create --verbose --preserve-permissions --bzip2 \
                --file={0}.tar.bz2 --listed-incremental={1} {2} {3} > {0}.log 2>&1'
                .format(os.path.join(backup_dir, backup_name),
                    os.path.join(backup_dir, metadata[0]),
                    backup_config['exclude_dirs'],
                    DIR_PATH))
    print command
    os.system(command)

mount(MOUNT_POINT, CREDENTIALS, NAS, backup_config['backup_dir'])
backup(backup_config['backup_dir'], backup_config['backup_name'])
remove_old_backups(backup_config['backup_dir'], backup_config['backups_to_keep'], backup_config['backup_name'])
unmount(MOUNT_POINT)
```

Answer (score 2):

One brief simple note, you could easily combine these functions:

```
def get_previous_backups(backup_dir):
    """Returns a list of tar.bz2 compressed backup files matching the date format"""
    return [os.path.basename(x) for x in
            glob.glob(backup_dir + DIR_PATH + host + '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' +
                '-[0-9][0-9]' + '-[0-9][0-9]' + '.tar.bz2')]

def get_metafile(backup_dir):
    """Returns the metadata file for incremental tar backups"""
    return [os.path.basename(x) for x in
            glob.glob(backup_dir + DIR_PATH + host + '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' +
                '-[0-9][0-9]' + '-[0-9][0-9]' + '.metadata')]
```

They're identical apart from the file extention, so just make that a parameter.

```
def get_previous_backups(backup_dir, extention):
    """Returns a list of backup files matching the date format and file extention"""
    return [os.path.basename(x) for x in
            glob.glob(backup_dir + DIR_PATH + host + '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' +
                '-[0-9][0-9]' + '-[0-9][0-9]' + '.' + extention)]
```

This also fixes the inaccurate docstring for `get_metafile` that didn't make it clear that a list was returned.

Answer (score 1):

A quick note from me: this function is subject to a race condition:

```
def mount(mount_point, credentials, nas, backup_dir):
    """Checks if the NFS share for the backup
    exists (if not it creates it) and mounts it"""
    if os.path.exists(mount_point):
        if not os.path.ismount(mount_point):
            subprocess.check_call(['mount', '-t', 'cifs', '-o', credentials, nas, mount_point])
            if not os.path.exists(backup_dir):
                os.makedirs(backup_dir)
    else:
        os.makedirs(mount_point)
        subprocess.check_call(['mount', '-t', 'cifs', '-o', credentials, nas, mount_point])
```

When you do a check of the form:

```
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

you’ll get an OSError if the directory pops into existence between your if condition and the makedirs() command. I suggest using something like this [mkdir_p() function from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600612), which creates the directory and ignores errors if it already exists.

Doing so would also let you cut out the duplicate subprocess calls:

```
def mount(mount_point, credentials, nas, backup_dir):
    mkdir_p(mount_point)
    if not os.path.ismount(mount_point):
        subprocess.check_call(['mount', '-t', 'cifs', '-o', 
                               credentials, nas, mount_point])
    mkdir_p(backup_dir)
```

Comment: Thank you! The mkdir_p function will do great in this code! Just one question, is there a reason why you put in this second mkdir_p call? As I see it, it just repeats the first call. Was that a mistake or is the second call necessary?

Comment: @Mortorq The two calls create two different directories; I was basing it on the two calls to os.makedirs() in the original function.

Comment: Whoops - of course!  I was a bit lazy while reading it and didn't read the arguments for the function. Sorry!